# Retrieving Local Resource Values correctly: GetGlobalResourceObject or .NET Control?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, msdn

While developing I've seen a couple different ways to get local resources values from the resx files. Which one is considered the best practice?

Using the GetGlobalResourceObject method:

```
<a id="myLink" href="#"><%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Filter","Diary")%></a>
```

Or using a control and setting the value directly in the resx:

Any better ways I should know?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: For middle and big projects, the best way is to implement Your own Resources Manager. For me .NET default resources manager sux, but it's my personal opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the names tell everything: Global Resources and Local Resources.

If you need the same resource to be used in different places (pages, controls, back-end, etc.) use Global Resources. 
Local resources are tight to pages and user controls. You should be creating one local source file for each page (aspx) and user controls (ascx).